# Upload document to mongodb

Tags: python, python-2.x, web-services, mongodb, bottle

Simple post and download web app in Bottle:

**server.py**

```python
import sys    
import bottle
from bottle import request, response
import pymongo
import gridfs
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

import mimetypes

mimetypes.init()


# Mongo Connection

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
db = connection.pacman
test_col = db.test
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)

# Static Routes
@bottle.get('/<filename:re:.*\.js>')
def javascripts(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root='static/js')


@bottle.get('/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
def stylesheets(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root='static/css')


@bottle.get('/<filename:re:.*\.(jpg|png|gif|ico)>')
def images(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root='static/img')


@bottle.get('/<filename:re:.*\.(eot|ttf|woff|svg)>')
def fonts(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root='static/fonts')


@bottle.route('/')
def home_page():
    result = db.fs.files.find({"filename": {"$exists": True}})

    return bottle.template('files_test/home', files=list(result))


@bottle.route('/add')
def add_page():
    return bottle.template('files_test/add')


@bottle.route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    data = request.files.data
    if data:
        raw = data.file.read()  # This is dangerous for big files
        file_name = data.filename
        try:
            newfile_id = fs.put(raw, filename=file_name)
        except:
            return "error inserting new file"
    print(newfile_id)
    return bottle.redirect('/')


@bottle.route('/download')
def download():
    file_id = ObjectId(bottle.request.query.id)
    if file_id:
        try:
            file_to_download = fs.get(file_id)
        except:
            return "document id not found for id:" + file_id, sys.exc_info()[0]
        file_extension = str(file_to_download.name)[(str(file_to_download.name).index('.')):]

        response.headers['Content-Type'] = (mimetypes.types_map[file_extension])
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + file_to_download.name
        response.content_length = file_to_download.length
        # print response
        return file_to_download

bottle.debug(True)
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

**add.tpl**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- pass in files (dict)-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Preformance and Capacity Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="data" /><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.tpl**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- pass in files (dict)-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Preformance and Capacity Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<br><br><br><br>
%for fileobj in files:
    Filename: {{fileobj['filename']}}<br>
    Size: {{fileobj['length']}}<br>
    Date Uploaded: {{fileobj['uploadDate']}}<br>
    md5: {{fileobj['md5']}}<br>
    <a href="download?id={{fileobj['_id']}}">&lt--Download File--&gt</a>


<br><br><br><br>
%end



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's on-topic now, but would be a better question if you edited it to include some of the information described in [What makes a good question?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/76/34757)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Global

You're hard coding the URL to your Mongo instance; it might be better to load it from a settings file. You're also not performing any authentication, though we'll assume that you have your firewalls properly set up, I guess. Some people prefer opening a new connection per request, up to you I guess. I would say that global variables suck, but if you don't think your program will expand beyond a single script, then it could be OK.

### Static views

You could combine all of the static views fairly simply; have one view that captures everything matching `<filename:re:.*\.(.+)>` (or whatever the correct regexp would be), and then have a dictionary mapping from extensions to directories:

```
STATIC_DIRS = {
    "jpg": "static/images",
    "gif": "static/images",
    ... # etc
}
```

That said, I don't see the advantage of being able to do `/foo.jpg` over `/static/images/foo.jpg`. Also, you could always eliminate the entire set of views and just serve your static content straight from the Nginx/Apache instance that is reverse proxying your application.

### Do Upload

I would **strongly** suggest you look into reading the file in chunks; as it is, your server would be trivial to DOS.

It might create nicer code if you reversed your `if` condition, so the code looked more like

```
@bottle.route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    data = request.files.data
    if not data:
        return bottle.redirect("/")

    raw = data.file.read()  # This is dangerous for big files
    file_name = data.filename
    try:
        newfile_id = fs.put(raw, filename=file_name)
    except:
        return "error inserting new file"
    print(newfile_id)
    return bottle.redirect('/')
```

This is known as a guard statement, and they are very nice.

Avoid using `try: ... except: ...` without specifying the type of the exception you wish to catch. In this case, it's particularly bad as you are not even logging the error; someone could come along, shoot a bullet through the hard drive of the machine you were running this on, and your service wouldn't note that anything of interest had happened. I'd suggest that when a request fails, you return a non-200 status code; at the moment, your bullet ridden hard drive will not cause a single non-200 status code.

### Download

If the file exists in Mongo, but not in the FS, currently you say `document id not found for id`. However, due to the `except` statement which doesn't specify exception types, your code also says that no matter what else goes wrong (recall the hard drive with a gun wound). I'd find out what class of errors come under the file not found category, and then treat them differently to others.

Currently, if the user looks up a file that doesn't exist, you return `None`, which I think bottle will complain about. It'd probably be better to add a guard clause along the lines of

```
if not file_id:
    # I don't know the bottle api for returning a particular status code, but something like this
    return bottle.abort(404)
... # otherwise serve the file
```

You don't handle the case that someone gives you a file you don't know the mimetype for, I'd recommend checking before you try and set the header.

### General

It's best to include a guard at the bottom of the file so that you can import the file without starting the webserver. I'd modify the last few lines to read

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bottle.debug(True)
    bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I haven't been able to configure a nginx reverse proxy and get it to work. Also, any suggestions on where I can learn some of the things you suggested? As I said, I'm not a full time coder.

Comment: Frankly setting up nginx/gunicorn is the part of python web development I hate the most. I usually refer to the gunicorn documentation (http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html), but I wouldn't worry too much in this case; if you're just developing an application, then I wouldn't worry about it. I'd focus on getting the application working correctly before worrying about stuff like performance :)

Comment: Thanks for the input! I decided to upload the project to Github and try to make your changes. Feel free to look in / contribute if you wanted. https://github.com/jdell64/IPACS

Comment: One more follow-up, you mentioned reading in chunks -- how do you do that?